# How set options for a QInputDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qinputdialog

I am trying to set some options for my `QInputDialog`. But if I call `getText` these settings have no effect.

How do I change the appearance of the window that pops up from `getText`?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore


class Mywidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Mywidget, self).__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.opendialog()

    def opendialog(self):
        inp = QtWidgets.QInputDialog()

        ##### SOME SETTINGS
        inp.setInputMode(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.TextInput)
        inp.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        inp.setOption(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.UsePlainTextEditForTextInput)
        p = inp.palette()
        p.setColor(inp.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.red)
        inp.setPalette(p)
        #####

        text, ok = inp.getText(w, 'title', 'description')
        if ok:
            print(text)
        else:
            print('cancel')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Mywidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [get*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#static-public-members) methods are all *static*, which means they can be called without having an instance of the `QInputDialog` class. Qt creates an *internal* dialog instance for these methods, so your settings will be ignored.

To get your example to work, you need to set a few more options and then show the dialog explicitly:

```
def opendialog(self):
    inp = QtWidgets.QInputDialog(self)

    ##### SOME SETTINGS
    inp.setInputMode(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.TextInput)
    inp.setFixedSize(400, 200)
    inp.setOption(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.UsePlainTextEditForTextInput)
    p = inp.palette()
    p.setColor(inp.backgroundRole(), QtCore.Qt.red)
    inp.setPalette(p)

    inp.setWindowTitle('title')
    inp.setLabelText('description')
    #####

    if inp.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
        print(inp.textValue())
    else:
        print('cancel')

    inp.deleteLater()
```

So now you are more or less reimplementing everything that `getText` does.